# pandas plot conditional values seaborn

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

My dataframe is,

```
      created_at            text
2017-03-01 00:00:01        power blah blah
2017-03-01 00:00:11        foo blah blah
2017-03-01 00:01:01        bar blah blah
2017-03-02 00:00:01        foobar blah blah
2017-03-02 00:10:01        hello world
2017-03-02 01:00:01        power blah blah
```

`created_at` is my index and its type is datetime64 which I can slice day by day easily. What I want to plot is that total number of entries day by day.
I separate this dataframe into its category, and plot them in one graph. But I think there is better way to do without having multiple dataframes

```
a = df[df["text"].str.contains("power")]
b = df[df["text"].str.contains("foo")]
c = df[df["text"].str.contains("bar")]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

df.groupby(df["created_at"].dt.date).size().plot(kind="bar", position=0)
a.groupby(a["created_at"].dt.date).size().plot(kind="bar", position=0)
b.groupby(b["created_at"].dt.date).size().plot(kind="bar", position=0)
c.groupby(c["created_at"].dt.date).size().plot(kind="bar", position=0)

plt.show()
```

I am learning `Seaborn`, so if solution is related to `Seaborn`, it would be nice, but it does not have to stick to it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: In case your categories are mutually exclusive, just add a "category" column and iterate over `df.groupby('category')`. Otherwise, the best you can do to clean up your code is use a for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to group-by days consider converting `df.index` to type `pd.DatetimeIndex` so you can use `df.resample()` as shown below:

```
# your original dataframe:
df = pd.read_json({"text":{"1488326401000":"power blah blah","1488326411000":"foo blah blah","1488326461000":"bar blah blah","1488412801000":"foobar blah blah","1488413401000":"hello world","1488416401000":"power blah blah"}})

# convert index to DatetimeIndex
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

# create function to do your calculations; not sure if this is exactly what you want
def func(df_):
    texts = ['power', 'foo', 'bar']
    d = dict()

    for text in texts:
        d[text] = df_['text'].str.contains(text).sum()

    return pd.Series(d)

# create your dataframe for plotting by resampling your data by each day and then applying the `func`
df_plot = df.resample('D').apply(func)

# do the plotting
df_plot.plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]